# Do these things validate a promise?

Tags: waswasa

I know that it doesn't get counted as a promise if you don't utter it out loud.
But what about the actions?
Under the extreme influence of OCD i made one promise to Allah which i regret now and which is illogical too.
I didn't utter anything but just shaked my head, thinking that I won't do a particular thing.
Was that valid???
Please help cause it makes me depressed so much to be in all this, thinking and making out clear all out of myself.

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question more than once; if you want to update the details of an existing question, use the "edit" link on that question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem since you didn't say anything out loud. I'm pretty sure Allah doesn't judge you on what you think, but he judges you on what you do and what you say.

Your OCD makes it harder for you (and you regret making that intention?). So I guess it doesn't really count and you can just forget about your intention and **I don't think it's valid, since you didn't say it out loud and you weren't 100% conscious** (because of your OCD).